# Using custom error in withCheckedThrowingContinuation

Tags: swift, async-await

I am unable to cause Xcode to accept the following code.

```
enum FooError : Error {}

class FooTest {
    func slowMethod() async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (c: CheckedContinuation<Void, FooError>) -> Void in
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the following compilation error:
`Cannot convert value of type '(CheckedContinuation<Void, FooError>) -> Void' to expected argument type '(CheckedContinuation<Void, any Error>) -> Void'. Arguments to generic parameter 'E' ('any Error' and 'FooError') are expected to be equal`

Is it possible for `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` to accept custom errors?

**Edit**

Following the comments below, this does not work either:

```
enum FooError : Error {}

class FooTest {
    func slowMethod() async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (c: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void in
            c.resume(throwing: FooError)
        }
    }
}
```

The error given is:
`Argument type 'FooError.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Error'`

Comment: No. Why do you want this? How is this useful, anyway?

Comment: Just leave it as `any Error`, you can still throw `FooError`, then check for the error type when you catch it. Imagine when you declare/call a function that `throws`, there is always no hint what the error type is. Throwing is always gonna be `any Error`

Comment: @RickyMo, this does not work either. I've updated my question to show why.

Comment: @UrK `FooError.bar` works.

Comment: `c.resume(throwing: FooError)` You are trying to throw the value type, not an actual value: `FooError.someErrorInTheEnum`

Comment: Thank all for helping. The issue was a different one. In the actual code `FooError` has an element `case bar(_ innerError: Error)`. Actual resolution was unable to create this `bar`. So the error message was not about failing to resolved `foo` to `Error`, but `innerError` to `Error`.
All the comments here did help me resolve the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding some basics.

```
enum FooError : Error {} // This on its own says that any `value` of `Type` FooError will conform to Error
```

`FooError` by itself is a `Type` not a `value`.

Now to get a `value` you need a `case` when dealing with an `enum`

```
enum FooError : Error {
    case someValueHere //This is a value
}
```

With your final code looking something like.

```
actor FooTest {
    func slowMethod() async throws  {
        try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation({ (c: UnsafeContinuation<Void, Error>) in
            c.resume(throwing: FooError.someValueHere)
        })
    }
}
```

Notice that since the return is a `Void` I am using `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation`

`withCheckedThrowingContinuation` expect you to call `c.resume(/* some return value */)`

You can extract a secondary `Error` if you use `LocalizedError`

```
enum FooError : LocalizedError {
    case someValueHere //This is a value
    case bar(_ innerError: Error)
    
    var errorDescription: String?{
        switch self {
        case .bar(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.localizedDescription
        default:
            return "\(self)".localizedCapitalized
        }
    }
    var failureReason: String?{
        switch self {
        case .bar(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.localizedFailureReason
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    var helpAnchor: String? {
        switch self {
        case .bar(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.helpAnchor
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    var recoverySuggestion: String? {
        switch self {
        case .bar(let error):
            let nsError = error as NSError
            return nsError.localizedRecoverySuggestion
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```